# Power BI not retrieving project online timephased data

Tags: odata, powerbi-desktop, project-online

I have entered work against some tasks in Project Online. However when pulling the OData feed down in Power BI the AssignmentBaselineTimePhased datasets and AssignmentTimephasedDatsets are empty, despite not having any filters applied in Power BI.

The summary data in AssignmentBaselines is available but being summary values only plots as dots. How can the timephased detail data be retrieved?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was actually that Microsoft have changed the default granularity of OData PWA feeds to "Never" for Timephased datasets. The purpose is to improve performance of the feeds by returning less data.

The fix is to change the reporting granularity in Project Online Reporting to (in this case) Daily:

[image]

Note: You'll have to republish your project for this to take effect.

MSDN blog post here: [Project Online: Changes to Granularity of Time phased OData](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/brismith/2017/11/29/project-online-changes-to-granularity-of-time-phased-odata/)